# Data persistence: Users' default setting and new setting

Tags: ios, data-persistence

I am building a project at the moment, if users set the default time is 20 minutes in View Controller A and users need to use this time as a timer in Controller B. 
I understand the data can be passed by delegation or notification, etc. 
What I am try to approach this by saving users' selection in View Controller A and retrieve in Controller B.
The approach include Core data, plist and NSUserdefault. Which one should I use in this case? Meanwhile, I am thinking the users' setting should be sync between iOS and Mac as well. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NSUserDefaults`. It is fine. But what do you mean by synching between iOS and Mac? Do you mean **Handoff** between devices??

Comment: No, I mean sync the setting information between iOS and Mac. I think iCloud would be the best one

Comment: One more thing is, how multiple View Controller can access the NSUserDefaluts?

Comment: UserDefaults provides a singleton instance for your app, so anywhere in your app UserDefaults can be accessed and written to.